# why would stein's unbiased risk estimate produce negative value?

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet

I am using wavelet decomposition together with SUREshrink on a 1-dimensional signal data for signal denoising and I realized SURE (Stein's Unbiased Risk Estimate) produces negative values. I can easily set the function to find the min of non-negative SURE and achieve my denoising result but what I would like to know is why SURE can produce a negative value? Intuitively, a risk estimate should not be negative?

Answer (score 0):

SUREshrink is a soft-thresholding operator, where small (magnitude) values are set to 0 and intermediate (magnitude) values are shrunk. keeping their sign. The 'risk' indicates the risk of different thresholds -- SURE minimises that risk.